# How do I deploy laravel securely with terminal to cpanel?

Tags: laravel, deployment, cpanel

How do I upload my files securely to Cpanel from the terminal? Also, is it possible to do a git push to Cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible using git.
[image: You will get a option called SSH Access]

[image: manage SSH Keys from here]

Then you can connect through your terminal.

```sh
ssh username@remote_host
```

Please read this [article to know more SSH Key Based Authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server)

After loging in you can goto desired directory and pull from git.